# Why xampp responding slowly when I use ip address instead of localhost

Tags: php, apache, xampp, ip, localhost

I am using xampp to run my php program on local server and it's working fine.

I want to run my program on different pc of same server network.
But when I use ip address instead of localhost on my pc, it's also work but responding slowly.

I have turned off my pc firewall but still it responding slowly.

Do I have to change in apache config file or on my php code or something else to get the same responding speed ?

Comment: uh.. how does the connection? sometimes, some adapter doesn't cut to serve..

Comment: using wifi network from a router ......